# Node script with Mongoose leaking memory

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a script that runs periodically with `setInterval`. This script is grabbing 1000 documents from a Mongo Database with Mongoose, and updating some of them. The script is described below in major aspects but after having the script run for a couple of days I see it is being killed by the OS for using up to 3GB of heap memory:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

clientModel = require('../prod-api/models/clientModel');
clients = mongoose.model('clients');
userModel = require('../prod-api/models/userModel');
users = mongoose.model('users');

// connect to Mongo
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
const config = require('./config');
mongoose.connect(config.mongo);

async function run() {
  let docCount = 0;

  clients.find({processed: false}).sort({timestamp: 1}).limit(1000).cursor()
    .on('data', async function(doc) {
      docCount++;

      const user = await users.findOne({_id: doc.user_id}).exec()
        .catch(() => console.log('[Error]: Getting User'));

      if (user) {
        // do something with user here
      }

      doc.processed = true;
      try {
        await doc.save()
        console.log(`[ * ] Saved ${doc._id}`);
      }
      catch (error) {
        console.log('[Error]: ' + error);
      }
    })
    .on('error', function(err){
      console.log('[Error] ' + err);
    })
    .on('end', function(){
      console.log(`[ - ] Done, documents processed: ${docCount}`);
    });
}

setInterval(run, 15000);
```

The node version I'm using is `v9.11.2` and this script is simply running on a screen session with the `forever` command. The error I see is:

```
FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: node::Abort() [/usr/bin/node]
 2: 0x8d05bc [/usr/bin/node]
 3: v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(char const*, bool) [/usr/bin/node]
 4: v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(char const*, bool) [/usr/bin/node]
 5: v8::internal::factory::NewFixedArray(int, v8::internal::PretenureFlag) [/usr/bin/node]
 6: v8::internal::HashTable<v8::internal::StringTable, v8::internal::StringTableShape>::NewInternal(v8::internal::Isolate*, int, v8::internal::PretenureFlag) [/usr/bin/node]
 7: v8::internal::HashTable<v8::internal::StringTable, v8::internal::StringTableShape>::New(v8::internal::Isolate*, int, v8::internal::PretenureFlag, v8::internal::MinimumCapacity) [/usr/bin/node]
 8: v8::internal::HashTable<v8::internal::StringTable, v8::internal::StringTableShape>::EnsureCapacity(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::StringTable>, int, v8::internal::PretenureFlag) [/usr/bin/node]
 9: v8::internal::StringTable::LookupString(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::String>) [/usr/bin/node]
10: 0x104018e [/usr/bin/node]
11: v8::internal::Runtime_KeyedGetProperty(int, v8::internal::Object**, v8::internal::Isolate*) [/usr/bin/node]
12: 0x3e78293842fd
error: Forever detected script was killed by signal: SIGABRT
```

The ideal candidate is `setInterval` but what other causes could be causing this memory leak and how to prevent this. Obviously my hopes for the GC where too high ?

Comment: Could you create a runnable example somewhere on github? I will profile. But first try to monitor the db with mongotop and currentOp for some 10-15 minutes of the script running. You are making 1001 find + up to 1000 update queries to mongo each 15 seconds. 15 millis per read-write might be just a bit too optimistic.